# PCL Kinfu in ROS Hydro

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to use Kinfu from PCL in ROS Hydro? The only package that I can find is [pcl17](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl17). However, this seems to be for Fuerte.

Can I safely install PCL 1.7 from the PCL website along ROS Hydro or will there be conflicts between the PCL libs included in ROS and the original libraries?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142461/pcl-kinfu-in-ros-hydro/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Step by Step (tested with Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Hydro; ros, ros version of pcl and cuda are installed!):

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.sh
mkdir pcl_workspace && cd pcl_workspace && catkin_make_isolated
mkdir -p src/pcl/ && cd src/pcl
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/groovy-unstable-devel/pcl/CMakeLists.txt
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/groovy-unstable-devel/pcl/package.xml
sed -i '/GIT_TAG/d' CMakeLists.txt
cd ../..
catkin_make_isolated
```

You can use our KinFuLS ros Wrapper (e.g. with kinect):

```
cd src && svn checkout http://fsstud.is.uni-due.de/svn/ros/is/kinfu && cd .. && catkin_make_isolated
source devel_isolated/setup.sh
roslaunch kinfu kinfu.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-03-26**:
Great! Does that work on Hydro?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2014-03-26**:
yes, tested with Hydro

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2014-10-27**:
Hi, If I run $catkin_make_isolated
it displays:
Could not find source space: /home/meng/pcl_workspace/src

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2014-10-27**:
It seems that it works! But how could the KinFu be visualized? Using Rviz???

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2014-11-06**:
yes, you can use rviz. Subscribe to /camera/kinfuLS/depth

**Comment by [Cansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/20807/cansen/) on 2014-11-13**:
Hi Michael,

I was trying to compile the PCL in the way that you suggested. However, I got the following errors that I don't know how to fix, could you help me?

make[5]: *** [octree/CMakeFiles/pcl_octree.dir/src/octree_inst.cpp.o] Error 1

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2014-11-13**:
Cansen, I need more information, please copy the error message

**Comment by [Cansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/20807/cansen/) on 2014-11-14**:
Hi Michael, I just found out the bug. To solve the problem, I need to change the cmake file: pcl-trunk → cmake → pcl_find_sse.cmake. replace "-march=native" with "-march=corei7". This solution can be found in pcl mailing list.

Thanks a lot!
Cansen

**Comment by [RokusO](https://answers.ros.org/users/19667/rokuso/) on 2014-12-01**:
Should this

```
cd src && http://fsstud.is.uni-due.de/svn/ros/is/kinfu && cd .. && catkin_make_isolated
```

not be the following?

```
cd src && svn co http://fsstud.is.uni-due.de/svn/ros/is/kinfu && cd .. && catkin_make_isolated
```

Everything else works perfectly by the way.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2014-12-01**:
@RokusO: thx

@Cansen: I would not call it a bug. Your compiler is just too old for your CPU

**Comment by [cvcook](https://answers.ros.org/users/23122/cvcook/) on 2015-09-15**:
When performing catkin_make_isolated on the pcl_trunk, I encountered:

```
make[5]: *** [io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io.dir/src/openni2_grabber.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io.dir/all] Error 2
```

Does anyone happen to know what might have gone wrong? Thx!

**Comment by [cvcook](https://answers.ros.org/users/23122/cvcook/) on 2015-09-16**:
I believe the error message to the make errors above was

```
/home/user/catkin_ws_boost/src/pcl/pcl_trunk/src/io/include/pcl/io/openni2/openni2_device.h:207:37: error: ‘class openni::Device’ has no member named ‘getDepthColorSyncEnabled’
```

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2015-09-16**:
I can remember there were several problems compiling PCL with openni2. Maybe this problem is not ROS related. Can you compile PCL without ROS?

**Comment by [cvcook](https://answers.ros.org/users/23122/cvcook/) on 2015-09-20**:
Yes, it seems that this is related to a openni2 problem that PCL might have. I'm not able to compile PCL without ROS, because of the same make error. Do you happen to remember the approach that you did to solve the openni2 problem? Thx again!

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2015-09-22**:
Sorry, I don't remember anything more about this problem. With my current system getDepthColorSyncEnabled is resolved in /usr/include/openni2/OpenNI.h installed with libopenni2-dev from the ROS repository (Ubuntu 14.04). You should check which OpenNI.h you are using.

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-03-27**:
Hi! Does anyone know will this work with ROS Kinetic?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2018-03-28**:
I do not think so, the code is 4 years old. I have newer code for ROS indigo, but it is a mess (it includes experimental code for map generation). I suppose you would need some experience to migrate it to Kinetic.

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-03-29**:
Ok. Which is currently the best way to use KinFu in ROS? I would like to test it on robot for 3D mapping and navigation.

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-04-09**:
@MichaelKorn
Hi Michael could you please check [this](https://bit.ly/2qhjy60) out and provide some guidelines. It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just curious what is Kinfu?  I was wondering just yesterday if installing PCL would mess up my hydro I have already installed, so I will be curious to see answer to this question.  Thankyou

---

Originally posted by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) with karma: 101 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-03-20**:
See here: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_kinfu_large_scale.php

**Comment by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on 2014-03-21**:
Meant to add this as a comment to above question.

**Comment by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on 2014-03-21**:
Thanks Kinfu and TSDF cloud looks really interesting.